# SQL Query to identify unequal values and present in transpose format

Tags: mysql, transpose

We have a CountryDtls table where country name, the activity performed and the year are present.
I need to identify only those rows where the year values are different between Arts and Academy and present it in a different format as given below

Original List:

```
Year  |CountryName |Activity  |
------|------------|----------|
1987  |India       |Arts      |
1987  |India       |Science   |
1876  |India       |Academy   |
1876  |Aus         |Arts      |
1836  |Aus         |Science   |
1876  |Aus         |Academy   |
1976  |USA         |Arts      |
1976  |USA         |Science   |
1976  |USA         |Academy   |
```

Expected Result:

```
CountryName |Arts |Academy |
------------|-----|--------|
India       |1987 |1876    |
```

I am able to achieve the results using the below query. Is there a better way of achieving the desired result?

```
select c.CountryName,(select Year from CountryDtls where environment="Arts" and c.CountryName=CountryName ) AS Arts 
,(select Year from CountryDtls where environment="Academy" and c.CountryName=CountryName ) as Academy from CountryDtls c where environment="Arts" AND environment="Arts" AND (CountryName) IN (SELECT CountryName FROM CountryDtls where environment="Academy") AND (Year) NOT IN (Select Year FROM CountryDtls where environment="Academy")
```

Comment: Use a self join.

Answer (score 0):

I think a self join (using sub-queries) provides the clearest solution:

```
SELECT
    Arts.CountryName,
    Arts.Yr AS Arts,
    Academy.Yr AS Academy
FROM
    (
        SELECT Yr, CountryName, Activity 
        FROM CountryDtls WHERE Activity = 'Arts'
    ) AS Arts
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT Yr, CountryName, Activity
        FROM CountryDtls WHERE Activity = 'Academy'
    ) AS Academy ON
        Academy.CountryName = Arts.CountryName
WHERE Arts.Yr <> Academy.Yr
```

If you have MySQL ≥ 8.0, you can use a CTE to make it a bit more readable:

```
WITH 
    Arts AS
    (
        SELECT yr, CountryName, Activity
        FROM CountryDtls WHERE Activity = 'Arts'
    ),
    Academy AS
    (
        SELECT yr, CountryName, Activity
        FROM CountryDtls WHERE Activity = 'Academy'
    )
SELECT
    Arts.CountryName,
    Arts.Yr AS Arts,
    Academy.Yr AS Academy
FROM Arts INNER JOIN Academy ON Academy.CountryName = Arts.CountryName
WHERE Arts.Yr <> Academy.Yr
```

Answer (score 0):

E.g.:

```
SELECT countryname
     , MAX(CASE WHEN activity = 'arts' THEN year END) arts
     , MAX(CASE WHEN activity = 'academy' THEN year END) academy 
  FROM my_table 
 GROUP 
    BY countryname 
HAVING arts <> academy;
```

or...

```
SELECT x.countryname
     , x.year arts
     , y.year academy 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.countryname = x.countryname 
   AND y.year <> x.year 
   AND y.activity = 'academy' 
 WHERE x.activity = 'arts';
```